# What is the difference between IP_MTU_DISCOVER values (IP_PMTUDISC_xxx)?

Tags: linux, ip, mtu

The `IP_MTU_DISCOVER` description from `man 7 ip` is too short. As far as I understand `IP_PMTUDISC_DONT` / `IP_PMTUDISC_DO` values enable/disable packet fragmentation on a route.

What are `IP_PMTUDISC_WANT` and `IP_PMTUDISC_PROBE`? What do they need for? How they affect IP traffic? Can they be used with UDP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MTU discovery doesn't necessarily mean that it's going to enable or disable packet fragmentation - it means that it's going to use [path MTU discovery](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1191) to adjust MTU sizes for a path to *avoid* fragmentation.

Don't mess with these settings unless you have a very good reason to do so, and you fully understand the changes that you're making; MTU discovery is a very good thing.

`IP_PMTUDISC_WANT` lets the setting be specifically defined on each route; in practice, it's essentially the same as `IP_PMTUDISC_DO`.

`IP_PMTUDISC_PROBE` is just for if you want to be able to send packets larger than the observed path MTU; this is probably not useful to you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have IP_PMTUDISC_WANT set by default on my Ubuntu. And in my network I have some routers which block ICMP packets. When I send UDP packets larger than MTU in some segment, the receiver never receive these packets. And now I understand why. It looks that I need to set IP_PMTUDISC_DONT for my UDP traffic.